# Delphi Upload on Ftp

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Well, i tried to upload delphi on ftp, using this code, it connects to server, but when it's time to uplaod a file, the program doesn't respond:

```
idftp1.host:='host';    
idftp1.username:='username';    
idftp1.passoword:='password';    
idftp1.port:='port';    

idftp1.connect;
idftp1.put('c:\testfile\testfile.txt','testfilee.html');    
idftp1.quit;    
idftp1.disconnect
```

any suggestions? thanks

Comment: You're doing it in the main thread, so it is normal that the program stop responding until the operation is finished. Move your code to a different thread if you want a responsive program. You can also rely on OnWorkStart/OnWorkEnd/OnWork events from Indy to get _feedback_ about how the upload is going.